# datetime do php retornando data errada

Tags: php

Até ontem a meia noite o codigo

```
$atual = new DateTime("now", new DateTimeZone($timezone));
```

retornava o horario normal, igual ao do servidor, mas hoje apresentou algo estranho.

```
2020-11-01 09:00:30 :: America/Rio_branco
2020-11-01 10:00:30 :: America/Manaus
2020-11-01 11:00:30 :: America/Bahia
2020-11-01 11:00:30 :: America/Fortaleza
2020-11-01 11:00:30 :: America/Cuiaba
2020-11-01 11:00:30 :: America/Campo_Grande
2020-11-01 11:00:30 :: America/Belem
2020-11-01 11:00:30 :: America/Recife
2020-11-01 10:00:30 :: America/Porto_Velho
2020-11-01 10:00:30 :: America/Boa_Vista
2020-11-01 11:00:30 :: America/Maceio
2020-11-01 12:00:30 :: America/Sao_Paulo
```

O timezone está correto no servidor, utc -03:00, e a hora exibida pelo OS tbm.

Mas algum dos timezones estão errado.
O que pode se fazer para corrigir isso?

Hora atual do servidor quando rodei o script :: (utc -03:00) :: 2020-11-01 11:00:30

Script para testar o erro.

```
function GetDates()
{
    $timezones = array(
        'AC' => 'America/Rio_branco',   'AM' => 'America/Manaus',
        'BA' => 'America/Bahia',        'CE' => 'America/Fortaleza',
        'MT' => 'America/Cuiaba',       'MS' => 'America/Campo_Grande',
        'PA' => 'America/Belem',
        'PE' => 'America/Recife',       'RO' => 'America/Porto_Velho',
        'RR' => 'America/Boa_Vista', 
        'SE' => 'America/Maceio',       'SP' => 'America/Sao_Paulo'   
    );
    $format = "Y-m-d H:i:s";                    

    foreach($timezones as $tz)
    {
        $serverTime = new DateTime("now", new DateTimeZone($tz));
        echo "<br>".$serverTime->format($format)." :: $tz";
    }

}

GetDates();
```

Comment: Configuração errada de horário de verão?

Comment: acredito que seja, mas não sei exatamente pelo o que procurar, no .ini não achei nada relacionado a `dst` ou `daylight saving`

Comment: Voltou ao normal? Por aqui parece estar tudo certo.2020-11-02 03:34:36 :: UTC
2020-11-02 00:34:36 :: America/Sao_Paulo
2020-11-01 23:34:36 :: America/Manaus
2020-11-01 22:34:36 :: America/Rio_branco

Comment: Não, com certeza tem alguma coisa com os arquivos do php que gerenciam o horário de verão da minha maquina, por hora fiz uma gambiarra para todos do gmt -3 usar o horario da bahia e os do -4 usar do amazonas